# Issue with char array of size one and strcat

Tags: c++, arrays, char

Ok, I'm really confused by this behaviour in VS2008.

This code..

```
char data[512] = "";

char c[1] = "";
c[0] = '1';

strcat(data, c);
```

.. results in `data` being set to this string value: `1ÌÌÌÌhÿ`

Surely it should just be `1`?

How can I ensure `data` only contains the single char[] that I copy into it (i.e. `1`)?

Why does `strcat()` copy all that garbage? Why does `c` even contain that garbage?

Thanks for any help

**Edit:** Thanks all.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem here is that you are passing an invalid value to strcat.  It expects the second parameter to be a valid c string value.  To be valid it must be an array / pointer of `char` values which ends with a null terminator (`\0`).  The value your are passing does not contain a null terminator and is hence invalid.

You need to define a null terminator for the string value `c` to be valid.  For example

```
char c[2];
c[0] = '1';
c[1] = '\0';
```

Answer (score 3):

Because strcat() copies C-String. C-Strings are '\0' terminated. So when you copy 'c' it starts there than searches through memory until it finds a memory location containg '\0' then copies all this into data.

What you need to do is make sure that 'c' is a real C-String ('\0' terminated)

```
char c[2] = {};  // Sets all members to '\0';
c[0]      = '1'; // Sets c[0] to '1' but leaves c[1] as '\0'

// c Is still a C-string as it is a sequence terminated with a '\0' character.
```

Answer (score 3):

No, it shouldn't be "just 1". Your `c` array is not a C-string, since you failed to zero-terminate it. When you pass something that is not a C-string to `strcat`, the behavior is undefined. This is what you observe in your case.

Note that it is simply impossible to squeeze a strung `"1"` into an array of size 1. You need array of at least 2 characters: one for `'1'` character and one for the zero-terminator character.

You can simply change your declaration of `c` to

```
char c[2] = "";
```

and the code will work as intended (the way I understand your intent).